# Copy a part of f06 file to a new text file

Tags: linux, grep

**If my f06 file (trial.f06) looks like**

```
RESULTS

TRIAL VALUES

ABCD

ABCD

ABCD

XX  1234

YY  1234

RESULTS

TRIAL VALUES

ABCD

ABCD

ABCD

ABCD

PP  1234

QQ  1234

RR  1234
```

**And I just want to copy all those *lines having numbers* into a text file, how should I do it?**

I tried this :

```
checkMessage =['grep -A 6 "TRIAL VALUES" trial.f06 > results.txt']; 

status4 = system(checkMessage);
```

But it gave me the file results.txt the same as above.

**This is for a LINUX machine**

Comment: Do you mean, in this case, you want the 4 lines ending in "1234"?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. But if there's any option where I can change the lines not ending in '1234' to HeaderLines using textscan, I'm open to it too.

Comment: You input data does not reflect what you have.  I the comment you are asking for lots of things.  Please change your data according to what you have, and also give example on what you like to get out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep` like this:

```
grep [0-9] trial.f06 > newfile.txt
```

**Output**:

```
XX  1234
YY  1234
PP  1234
QQ  1234
```

If you mean you want all lines containing numbers in the 6 lines following the words "TRIAL VALUES", you can do this:

```
grep -A6 "TRIAL VALUES" trial.f06 | grep [0-9] > newfile.txt
```

Comment: It works. But I'm sorry, I forgot to mention, that in my whole f06 file, there are other lines too that have numbers (which I forgot to mention in the original question) and I just want these few lines that I have shown. Now can you provide a solution?

Comment: Then pipe the grep into something like this `| sed '4q'` to only get the first 4 matches

Comment: Do you mean you only want the first 4 results? Or do you mean you only want lines specifically containing 1234 at the end? Or how do I differentiate the ones you want or don't want?

Comment: You are right on saying that I want only those lines specifically containing some particular values at the end (1234 is just for example. They might be all different values at the end like 123456, 7656787, 6545, 32454 etc). Also, those lines are not the first 4 results, as I have just written a part of my file as an example in order to ask for help.

Comment: So, do you want all lines with a digit at the end maybe?

Comment: No, only the lines with digits under the heading "trial values".

Comment: Maybe you mean you want lines with digits only found in the 6 lines after the words "TRIAL VALUES"?

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, "TRIAL VALUES" appears twice in the f06 file.

Comment: So which one do we want? The first? The second? The last? All except the first?

Comment: I think, it's just getting confusing. I'll just explain what I want clearly. I have a huge file with different values and numbers. There is a part of the file somewhere in between which is the one I have mentioned in the original question. I want those lines with digits under the heading "TRIAL VALUES". But since this heading appears twice, I'm not able to get all the 4 lines with digits together in one text file. 
I want the output to look like
XX  1234
YY  1234
PP  1234
QQ  1234
(where 1234 is just for example. The digits can be anything)

Comment: Your question is unclear and you didn't answer which set of Trial Values you want. So, I'll ask differently and say "What is wrong with my answer?"

Comment: Your edited version of the answer works for my case! Thanks a lot.